# Different definitions of lapse functions?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, adm-formalism

I stumbled over two different definitions of the lapse function in the ADM formalism and wanted to convince myself that they are the same by using a simple example. However, I get different results, so I think I am doing somthing wrong.

Consider the manifold $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ with metric $g$ given by

$$g_{\mu\nu}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}\mathrm{d}x^{\nu}=a(\lambda)^{2}(-\mathrm{d}t^{2}+\delta_{ij}\mathrm{d}x^{i}\mathrm{d}x^{j})$$

So, the example I take is essentially FRW with conformal time $\lambda$. As a foliation of this space in space-like hypersurfaces, I choose embeddings
$$i_{\lambda}:\mathbb{R}^{3}\to\mathbb{R}^{4}$$
$$(x,y,z)\mapsto (a(\lambda),x,y,z)$$
So, the embedded surface $\Sigma_{\lambda}:=i_{\lambda}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$ is just the slice of constant "time" $a(\lambda)$. Now, there are the following two definitions I found:

1. The more standard definition used in many textbooks is the following. Consider the hypersurface $\Sigma_{\lambda_{0}}$. It can be defined by the condition
   $$\varphi(\lambda,x,y,z):=a(\lambda_{0})-\lambda=0.$$
   Then, one defines the vector $X^{\mu}$ via the condition
   $$X^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\phi=1$$
   which yields
   $$X^{\mu}=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$
   Then, the lapse can be defined as $N_{\lambda_{0}}:=-X^{\mu}n_{\mu}$, where $n_{\mu}$ denotes the normal vector field, which is given by $n_{0}=a(\lambda_{0})^{2}, n_{i}=0$. Hence, for the hypersurface $\Sigma_{\lambda_{0}}$, we find the lapse
   $$N_{\lambda_{0}}=a(\lambda_{0})^{2}.$$
2. The other definition, starts by defining maps $X_{\lambda}:\mathbb{R}^{3}\to\mathbb{R}^{4}$ via $\partial i_{\lambda}/\partial\lambda$. For some fixed $\lambda_{0}$, we hence find
   $$X^{\mu}=\begin{pmatrix}\dot{a}(\lambda_{0})\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
   This can be splitted up in a normal and tangential part. The multiple of the normal part to the normal vector is then the laps function, which using $n^{\nu}=(1/a(\lambda_{0})^{2},0,0,0)$ gives
   $$N_{\lambda_{0}}=a(\lambda_{0})^{2}\dot{a}(\lambda_{0}).$$

What am I doing wrong?